# Using Decimal.ToString() without rounding up the number

Tags: c#, decimal

I have following decimal number

```
string number = "60.9";
Response.Write(Convert.ToDecimal(number).ToString("#,0")); // prints 61
```

I want to format the value like 99,999,999... but if the value has decimal point, it is getting rounded up

Please let me know how can I print 60.9, instead of 61 with same number formatting

Comment: Wait! What's the point of this code? String -> Decimal -> String->display. Why not just display the string?

Comment: And why is there a custom format string? Simply `ToString()` would do what you want in any case.

Comment: Yes, this question is missing some crucial information...

Comment: @danish: this is just sample example

Comment: i think it might be better for you if you used `decimal.Parse()` and then print it the way you want `ToString()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `N` format. This will show the number with group separator of your locale (`,` for US locale for example, although you can optionally influence that), and leave decimal part as it is:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(number).ToString("N")
```

**Update.** After some discussion in comments the approach that meets all requirements appeared to be

```
Convert.ToDecimal(number).ToString("#,#.##########", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Kudos to [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon).

Comment: This won't leave the decimal part as-is. It will print exactly as many decimal digits as the current culture's formatting rules stipulate (which probably means 2, so `60.90`).

Comment: @Jon, oh, did not know that, thanks. Is there any way to work this around (since N is very close to what OP needs in other respects)? I guess you can set `NumberFormatInfo`, but it seems a bit of overhead here.

Comment: This works in my case but if the value do not have decimal point for example-  for '1234' it prints '1234.00' which I dont want. any workaround for this?

Comment: @MicrosoftDN: Is something wrong with just `.ToString()`?

Comment: @MicrosoftDN: `ToString("#,#.##########", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. The number of trailing #s should be the maximum number of decimal digits you want to display (if there are more there will be rounding). Feel free to spam 20 of them if you want all decimals to show.

Comment: @Jon, that works better than what I suggested. In fact `N` does not  work as OP needs. Can you place it in a separate answer, so that I could delete mine?

Comment: @Andrei: Edit the comment into your answer and keep the check mark instead. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A custom (no the best but it's works) solution:

```
public static string FormatDecimal(string value, bool addSign = true, bool showDecimals = true)
{
    if (value == null)
    { return ""; }

    var r = value.Replace("$", "");

    if (showDecimals)
    {
        r = Convert.ToDecimal(r).ToString("C").Replace("$", "");
    }
    else
    {
        var newFormat= "";
        r = Convert.ToDecimal(r).ToString("C").Replace(".00", "").Replace("$", "");
        for (int i = 0; i < r.Length; i++)
        {
            if (r[i] == '.')
            {
                break;
            }
            newFormat += r[i];
        }
        r = newFormat;
    }


    if (addSign)
    {
        r = "RD$" + r;
    }

    return r;
}
```